# Estimating the value of a random number

Tags: probability, probability-theory, approximation, parameter-estimation

Consider variables $y$, $A$ and $B$ and the following relationship between them:

$$y = A + B.$$

$A$ has a uniform distribution between $[0,K]$.
Distribution of $B$ is unknown, but $B$ is a random number and is not constant with $B > A$. It is also OK to assume that $B \gg A$ if that helps.

Let us say that there is a generator that generates values of $y$.

Given $N$ such samples of $y$ values, I want to calculate the following:

1. The mean value of $B$'s distribution (For example, if $B$ was also a uniform random number with distribution $[0,L]$, the answer will be $L/2$. But the challenge is that we don't know $B$'s distribution).
2. The contribution of $B$ to the value of $y$ in those $N$ samples. Approximate contribution is fine. So in each value of $y$ in the $N$ samples, how much part came from $B$.

Are there any heuristics/approximations to solve the following problem? Or any standard method?

Comment: $$E[y]=E[A] + E[B]$$

$E[A]$ is known and $E[y]$ can be estimated from the $y$ sampling, so...

Comment: Can we estimate E[y] from the sampling no matter what the value of N is? I feel like if the number of samples is very low, the average of all the samples will not be E[y] considering E[y] as the mean of the random variable y. The key challenge here is that N can be small as well as large. When N is very large, your solution applies. But with small N, I don't think we can get the mean of the distributions based on a simple average. Let me know if you think this is wrong.